# adding dynamic div to another div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have the following code in html, js and css.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function add() {
            for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
            var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );
            var d = document.createElement( 'div' );
            d.id = "new1";
            d.innerHTML = i.innerHTML ;
            var p = document.getElementById('new');
            p.appendChild(d);
        }

    }    
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="old" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <select>
            <option value="pls">Please</option>
            <option value="1">&lt</option>
            <option value="2">&gt</option>
            <option value="3">=</option>
        </select>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
        </div>

        <hr/>
        <div id="new" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <input type="button" value="go"/>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <button onclick="add();">Add</button><br>        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here i am trying to display dynamic div on click of add button. it is adding simply, but the div is visible by default, so i am hiding it through css style=" hidden". now on click of add button it is adding but the div is hidden.
Here i am facing a problem how to show the div (here looping i.e 4).

And the go button will come below of it.

Also I am using css like ternary operator. e.g.
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "hidden") ? "visible" : "hidden";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really puzzled what you are trying to achieve. You should either create the new div like this

```
<div id="new">
```

Or you should make the div visible on the first click. Add to your function this

```
p.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

You can see this http://jsfiddle.net/tkKun/ for the former example

Comment: If you want the button come down then you have to insert your divs before it. Instead of:
`p.appendChild(d);`
you should do
`p.insertBefore(d, p.firstChild);`

Comment: yes i got it. Is there any way to get those dynamic div id value. means d.id = "div"+j; will generate id's. i need to print in which textbox what has entered based on id.

Answer (score 0):

the created divs are hidden because you added them under div "new" which have the style visibility:hidden.

to get them displayed, simply add this line to the bottom of the add function:

```
p.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

when you create new divs, it is not recommended give all of them the same id new1, its better assign the id of each new div with the j value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.createNode();
```

or plain text

```
var foo = '<div> bar </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries, finally I have found the answer,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function add() {

            for(var j=0;j<4;j++){

            var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );
            var d = document.createElement( 'div' );
            d.id = "div"+j;
            d.innerHTML = i.innerHTML ;
            var p = document.getElementById('new');
            p.style.visibility = 'visible';
            p.appendChild(d);           

        }
        var d = document.createElement( 'div' );
        var l = document.getElementById('one');
        l.style.visibility = 'visible';
        l.appendChild(d);

    }    
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="old" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <select>
            <option value="pls">Please</option>
            <option value="1">&lt</option>
            <option value="2">&gt</option>
            <option value="3">=</option>
        </select>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
        </div>

        <hr/>
        <div id="new" style="visibility:hidden;">

        </div>
        <div id="one" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <br/><input type="button" value="go"/>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <button onclick="add();">Add</button><br>        
    </body>
    </html>
```